# Can my BaseController have a method return a redirect or true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

That title is misleading, but I'm not sure how to word it better.

My controllers all inherit from BaseController. I would like to have a method in the BaseController that I can call from various actions. I would like something like this:

```
public virtual object CheckValues(Guid value1, string value2)
{
    if (value2 == const_SomeValue || value1 == GetCurrentId())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Basically, I would like tho have a method that will check certain things and if it fails, does a Redirect. My controller action would check it like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult overview(Guid? id)
{
    CheckValues(id, string.Empty); // on fail this redirects

    // Continue with this Action
    return View();
}
```

Many of my controller actions would make use of the `CheckValues` method.

Is there a good or correct way to do this?

***Update:*** I wanted to share my solution. I liked how it came out.

My controller can now look like this:

```
[CheckId()] // I can overload the name of the Id, the redirect Action and/or contoller
public virtual ActionResult overview(Guid? id)
{
    //... Logic for my action
    return View();
}
```

My filter looks like this:

```
public class CheckIdAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string IdValue { get; set; }
    public string RedirectAction { get; set; }
    public string RedirectController { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // I wanted to be able to override the redirect and 
        // the name of the id to check if necessary. Or just
        // use defaults.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IdValue))
            IdValue = "id";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RedirectAction))
            RedirectAction = "index";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RedirectController))
            RedirectController = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

        var isValue1Valid = filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(IdValue) &&
            (filterContext.ActionParameters[IdValue] != null && (Guid)filterContext.ActionParameters[IdValue] != Guid.Empty);

        if (!isValue1Valid)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = RedirectAction, controller = RedirectController }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to have an action that returns an action in a BaseController, that sends the user to a view relative to the controller that you're working with. But returning a RedirectToAction as an Object is nasty; why not make two actions in the base. One to return a bool, and depending on the result of that jump to the redirect from your controller.

Comment: Hmm... good idea. I didn't like my idea much. I like clean and pattern based.

Comment: Alternatively, move the bool returning function somewhere else (a different class or service, away from the controller), leaving just the Action in your BaseController. That cleans your controller even further and keeps things tidier. :)

Comment: Could I do something like passing a delegate, something like `CheckValues(Guid value1, string value2, Func<ActionResult, Guid> myMethodName)`. Then I could do my Redirect on fail, or just run a method that would return the View.

Comment: Seems like you should be using action filters for this, not base class methods.

Comment: That is possible, but try to keep the logic clear so people don't lose track of the flow through your actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to base class methods is action filters. Your controller action could look like this:

```
[CheckValues(Value1 = "id", Value2 = "")]
public ActionResult overview(Guid? id)
{
    // Continue with this Action
    return View();
}
```

Then in the action filter, override `OnActionExecuting` to check the parameters and possibly redirect.

```
public class CheckValuesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public string Value1 { get; set; }
  public string Value2 { get; set; }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    var isValue2Valid = filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(Value2) &&
                        filterContext.ActionParameters[Value2] == const_SomeValue;
    var isValue1Valid = filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(Value1) &&
                        filterContext.ActionParameters[Value1] == GetCurrentId();

    if (!isValue1Valid || !isValue2Valid)
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index"}));
  }
}
```

The above would still need some tweaking to deal with the case when `Value2` is missing/empty string and casting `Value1` to a Guid, but that's the gist of it. The line where you set `filterContext.Result` would short-circuit your action so that it actually never gets executed -- the redirect would happen before the request ever made it to your controller action.

Comment: I knew I'd seen something like that, but couldn't remember the name. Thanks. REsearching.

Comment: Nice and clean solution.

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to get `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` in the filter?

Comment: @MKenyonII yes you can find it in `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`